# Copy data from table to another table MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having a problem updating newly added records that don't have a timestamp to another identical table in the same database.  Here is my query

```
INSERT INTO mlscopy
SELECT * FROM mls_cvrmls AS parent
LEFT JOIN mlscopy AS child
ON child.listing_listnum != parent.listing_listnum
```

The parent table is updated by a separate company every morning, and unfortunately there are no timestamps(datetime) to relate the newly added records.

My child table(the copy) is needed for google geocoding since their morning udpates drop and create the parent table each morning.

I made a structure and data copy of the parent table, then deleted the last ten records to test my query. But I keep receiving the error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

Can't think of what I'm doing wrong here.

Here are the column table names

```
listing_listing
listing_listnum
listing_propertytype
listing_status
listing_listingpublicid
listing_agentname
listing_agentlist
listing_listingbrokercode
listing_officelist
listing_lo
listing_lo00
listing_lo01
listing_lo02
listing_lo03
listing_lo04
listing_lo05
listing_agentcolist
listing_agentcolist00
listing_officecolist
listing_area
listing_listdate
listing_listprice
listing_streetnumdisplay
listing_streetdirectional
listing_streetname
listing_streettype
listing_countyid
listing_zipcode
listing_zipplus4
listing_postoffice
listing_subdivision
listing_neighborhood
listing_schoolelem
listing_schooljunior
listing_schoolhigh
listing_pud
listing_lotdim
listing_acres
listing_zoning
listing_sqfttotal
listing_sqftunfinished
listing_rooms
listing_bedrooms
listing_stories
listing_basement
listing_garage
listing_garagecap
listing_fireplaces
listing_pool
listing_bathsfull
listing_bathshalf
listing_bathstotal
listing_bathsfullbsmt
listing_bathsfulllevel1
listing_bathsfulllevel2
listing_bathsfulllevel3
listing_bathshalfbsmt
listing_bathshalflevel1
listing_bathshalflevel2
listing_bathshalflevel3
listing_roombed2desc
listing_roombed2length
listing_roombed2level
listing_roombed2width
listing_roombed3desc
listing_roombed3length
listing_roombed3level
listing_roombed3width
listing_roombed4desc
listing_roombed4length
listing_roombed4level
listing_roombed4width
listing_roombed5desc
listing_roombed5length
listing_roombed5level
listing_roombed5width
listing_roomdiningdesc
listing_roomdininglength
listing_roomdininglevel
listing_roomdiningwidth
listing_roomfamilydesc
listing_roomfamilylength
listing_roomfamilylevel
listing_roomfamilywidth
listing_roomfloridadesc
listing_roomfloridalength
listing_roomfloridalevel
listing_roomfloridawidth
listing_roomfoyerdesc
listing_roomfoyerlength
listing_roomfoyerlevel
listing_roomfoyerwidth
listing_roomgreatdesc
listing_roomgreatlength
listing_roomgreatlevel
listing_roomgreatwidth
listing_roomkitchendesc
listing_roomkitchenlength
listing_roomkitchenlevel
listing_roomkitchenwidth
listing_roomlaundrydesc
listing_roomlaundrylength
listing_roomlaundrylevel
listing_roomlaundrywidth
listing_roomlivingdesc
listing_roomlivinglength
listing_roomlivinglevel
listing_roomlivingwidth
listing_roommasterbrdesc
listing_roommasterbrlength
listing_roommasterbrlevel
listing_roommasterbrwidth
listing_roomofficedesc
listing_roomofficelength
listing_roomofficelevel
listing_roomofficewidth
listing_roomother1desc
listing_roomother1length
listing_roomother1level
listing_roomother1width
listing_roomother1
listing_roomother2desc
listing_roomother2length
listing_roomother2level
listing_roomother2width
listing_roomother2
listing_roomrecdesc
listing_roomreclength
listing_roomreclevel
listing_roomrecwidth
listing_handicap
listing_yearbuilt
listing_lotdesc
listing_construction
listing_watertype
listing_roof
listing_attic
listing_style
listing_floors
listing_fireplacedesc
listing_structure
listing_walltype
listing_basedesc
listing_appliances
listing_interior
listing_exterior
listing_amenities
listing_pooldesc
listing_fence
listing_porch
listing_heatsrc
listing_heatsystem
listing_coolsystem
listing_waterheater
listing_watersewer
listing_parking
listing_garagedesc
listing_handicapdesc
listing_feedesc
listing_restrictions
listing_terms
listing_assocfeeincludes
listing_building
listing_possession
listing_farmtype
listing_ownerdesc
listing_irrigationsrc
listing_taxyear
listing_taxamount
listing_directions
listing_remarks
listing_virtualtourlink
listing_vowavmyn
listing_vowcommyn
listing_addressdisplayyn
listing_f174
listing_proptype
listing_lat
listing_lon
listing_photo1
listing_listofficename
listing_vtoururl
listing_multiphotoflag
    id <- primary key
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only run the `SELECT` statement from your `INSERT` you will see that your select returns all the columns of **both** `mls_cvrmls` AND `mlscopy`.

You probably need:

```
INSERT INTO mlscopy
SELECT parent.* FROM mls_cvrmls AS parent
LEFT JOIN mlscopy AS child
ON child.listing_listnum != parent.listing_listnum
```

---

**EDIT**

I am not sure your JOIN condition is correct. This kind of condition will probably return many records you did not wish for. Each record in `mls_cvrmls` has many (many!) records in `mlscopy` which satisfy the condition.

As an example, let's assume the 2 tables have 3 columns, and you want to add all records from parent to child, as long as they don't exists there anymore.

```
INSERT INTO mlscopy (listing_listing, listing_listnum, listing_propertytype)
SELECT parent.listing_listing, 
       parent.listing_listnum, 
       parent.listing_propertytype  // (more columns...)
FROM mls_cvrmls AS parent
LEFT JOIN mlscopy AS child 
     ON child.listing_listnum = parent.listing_listnum
WHERE child.listing_listnum IS NULL
```

Comment: Added the tables column names.  From your query I get unknown table mls_cvrmls

Comment: @Andre - do both parent and child have the same columns (all of them)?

Comment: @Andre :) comments like this make SO worth the effort!

Comment: Yes they both have the same columns

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3633/discussion-between-andre-dublin-and-galz)

Comment: Downvvoted for not specifically listing columns which a sql antipatten. SELECT * should not be used in production code and it is even worse to use it in an insert. This is a manitnenance issue just waiting to break or worse not break but cause data integrity problems (becasue someone else who used select * rearranged the column in one table but not the other rather than specify columns when they wanted a differnt order). Very poor technique. Antipatterns should not be accepted answers.

Comment: @HLGEM did you bother to read through and get to the secong query? The first was enough to explain to Andre why his query failed.

Comment: Second query is still bad becasue it doesn't list the insert columns in order. Still a SQL Antipattern.

Comment: @HLGEM - corrected. Thanks. (a downvote is one option, an edit of the answer to make it better is another)

Comment: @Galz, got your attention didn;t it?

Comment: @HLGEM: In Galz's defense, the original version of the question didn't list the fields, that was a later edit, so maybe at the time he posted his answer all he had to go on was "*".

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things here.

1. The error message is because "select *" gives you all columns from all tables in the query. That is, each row has all the columns from mls_cvrmls PLUS all the columns from mlscopy. This is not going to be suitable for inserting into mlscopy because it's going to have many extra columns. If the two tables have all the same columns, then they will all be doubled.
2. Your WHERE clause is unlikely to be correct. This is saying that for every row in parent, you want all the rows in child that don't match. Think this through. Suppose parent has listing_listnum values of 1, 2, and 4, and child has value 1, 4, and 5. So the pairs 1/1 and 4/4 will be excluded. But you'll get the pairs 1/4, 1/5, 2/4, 2/5, 4/1, and 4/5. I think what you really want here is to just get the records from parent that aren't found on child at all, like in this example, just 2. So what you probably really want is a "not exists" query.
3. I'm not entirely clear from your description, but you say you want to "update newly added records", but then you do an INSERT. Do you want to update existing records, or do you want to insert new records?

So assuming that what you want to do is find records that are in mls_cvrmls but not in mlscopy and insert these records, I think the correct query would be more like -- and your field list is long so I'll just pick a few sample fields to make the point:

```
insert into mlscopy (listing_listing, listing_listnum, listing_propertytype, listing_status    
    listing_listingpublicid, listing_agentname)
select listing_listing, listing_listnum, listing_propertytype, listing_status    
    listing_listingpublicid, listing_agentname
from mls_cvrmls
where not exists (select 1 from mlscopy where mlscopy.listing_listnum=mls_cvrmls.listing_listnum)
```

As Icarus says, you should list all columns explicitly. Among the many reasons for this, even if the two tables have all the same fields, if they do not occur in the same order, "insert into mlscopy select *" will not work, because a SQL engine does not match names, it just takes the fields in each table in the order they occur. This may seem like a pain if the list is long, but trust me, after you've been burned a few times by mysterious problems, you'll want to list the fields explicitly.

And just a side note: Why do you prefix all the column names with "listing_" ? This just makes more to type every time you use the table. If you have another table that has names that would otherwise be the same and you need to distinguish, you can always prefix with the table name, like "mls_cvrmls.propertytype".

Answer (score 2):

Get used to list-all-your-columns and you will save yourself some headaches like this and in the future your code won't break if they add more columns.

Change your sql statement to something like this

```
INSERT INTO mlscopy (col1,col2,col3...coln)
SELECT col1,col2,col3....coln FROM mls_cvrmls AS parent
LEFT JOIN mlscopy AS child
ON child.listing_listnum != parent.listing_listnum
```

Comment: Absolutely. An insert should not be written using select * or wihtout specyfiyng the insert columns! Heck even if someone rearranges the column order  (you should not do this but it happens especially when people use select * instead of specifying the columns because that's the only way they know to get the columns in the order they want.), the intial query could go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The two tables have different structures, and you're not specifying WHICH fields would be copied across. If you must have different structures, you'll have to explicitly state WHICH fields should be copied. MySQL isn't smart enough to figure that sort of mismatch out on its own, so it complains and aborts.